# How to add parametr to method of class?

Tags: typescript

I want to do analog static property of function in php

I created interface.

```
interface TInterf { (lang: any): any; countries: any; }
```

I created class with method.

```
class Test {
 constructor() {
  this.methodTest.param = '1';
 }

 public methodTest = <TInterf>() => {
  console.log(this.methodTest.param);
 }
}
```

Error: property does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface defines `countries`, but your implementation is using the name `param`. Note that what you're adding is a *property*, not a parameter.

In general, I don't think adding properties to functions is best practice in TypeScript, and it's awkward to do (though possible) because JavaScript and TypeScript don't have a literal form for functions that allows adding additional properties. So you basically have to use a helper function (a dedicated one, or `Object.assign`).

Here's a dedicated one that offers some type checking at the point you're creating the function, see comments:

```typescript
interface TInterf {
    (lang: any): any;
    param: any; // *** Note changed name to match other code
}

// A helper function to turn a near-TInterf into an actual TInterf by applying `param`
function createTInterf(implementation: (lang: any) => any, param: any): TInterf {
    const method = implementation as TInterf;
    method.param = param;
    return method;
}

class Test {
    // No constructor needed anymore

    // Use the helper function to create the function. Note that this is an *instance*
    // method, not a prototype method, but it does work
    public methodTest = createTInterf(
        // Note the type annotation for `this` so we know what it is in the function
        function (this: Test, lang: any) {
            console.log(this.methodTest.param);
        },
        '1'
    );
}

const t = new Test();
t.methodTest("some language");
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoElzRsg3gWAChkTkAKAGzhAHMAuZagTwEoHmBuI05ABzihwAtuxBMOyAPSTkAKnnIAcgHtIyBAAtqNCABNkIYSjDLkQuGE3JVG6OuW6IRAL5Ei05AEFktirzswAK4gCGDAyiDIJlGBUJFwBhACALQYWLDIoNHUjKGBcBRomJAZAEZMjLy8FEygNMgABvyCQg1EQSFhEepQSZBpJTBkwELVEEIQ4BbhIAyU2qKsyAC8AHyMYgA0fALCi2xF6TgExKQIEQDOYGYQYBoOK5mjFOOTYNPdcBeHg1ynJBM7g4AHTNYSPMFCP48XpgWKRQH3XR-VyEIgIKgXb6oCBXPDcUgeFT2EBXKCBULKKCJPR6DZMIRUpxo-5SGQAVQuxlsPggfgCwVCMyipgQvQs3JQHSFEWBSlU3IsUQ0wG+qo2clAV2oSFkBJIHkRDm2IFUjD4UFUqiY-huQN021KgWuwGuumUuOQAHcqQBrfV8QKlCjABB2pE4vHLHp9CADbBkAM8IkK5XGG0oaim95dSIwKmNO6qhrIC6mL0oX2mr3erQul1qyJ3KWC3NJ0jS3PkIsXBiRsDbKi0fb41k8HjnUnKF7AijKGhkHvAo26fug3ZCFjQ8ckZybdskADkAEZDwGty43IRJ3jrtGQBAa-2yBfCGBl7cI7iwGQAERliZkCHGh8h0X9XyAA)

Or using `Object.assign`, which doesn't offer type checking at the point you're creating the function:

```typescript
interface TInterf {
    (lang: any): any;
    param: any; // *** Note changed name to match other code
}

class Test {
    // No constructor needed anymore

    // Use `Object.assign` to create the function. Note that this is an *instance*
    // method, not a prototype method, but it does work
    public methodTest: TInterf = Object.assign(
        // Note the type annotation for `this` so we know what it is in the function
        function (this: Test, lang: any) {
            console.log(this.methodTest.param);
        },
        {param: '1'}
    );
}

const t = new Test();
t.methodTest("some language");
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoElzRsg3gWAChkTkAKAGzhAHMAuZagTwEoHmBuI05ABzihwAtuxBMOyAPSTkAKnnIAcgHtIyBAAtqNCABNkIYSjDLkQuGE3JVG6OuW6IRAL5EiCKgGdPaCJ7B43KTSSqYIyiD+UACuCCZQBhB6eoxiQspQToRBJCEAqp4oAAYA8gBGAFYQcQB0cN7ANCBFyCbqmRbGtsgw0SBxwBE1oWpgWgFjwD5TqXKg-tRIsjlSMkIQYw4ANAaqjHxQqqpMvCjrm7o7ZdEBwAG6yn7IAO4ZANYrvNFlFMAIZhsNA5UH4wAwMFhYMgALzIcpVWr1TyNEBkFY8EIqUbdMAnFDUECqCyDEA9DLIIqTTwtTymZ4oN6E54vcbIO5s6aksYoXr9MAk9GkXkDCLkKng0E7Ki0USsQLEHiKkjhSLKCgQGoUZQ0MhUmrnIG6EH+Gr8QRCFhcBVK5xbQUkXBm4QMADkAEYXa5rchLS43IQVf5WjDEszjWAyL7CGB9YDgaCyAAiWnrZDSmjROA6RNRoA)

---

Side note: I recommend avoiding `any` as a type. I'm guessing you used it in this example just to be very general, but there's little point in using TypeScript at all if using `any` as the type of everything. :-)